# Typescript - Polymorphism with data model interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface, polymorphism

I think I am looking for a design pattern here. Here is what I have -

**IApp.ts**

```
export interface IApp {
   platform: PlatformEnum;
   version: string;
   islive: boolean;
   title: string;
   iconurl: string;
}
```

**IAppleApp.ts**

```
export interface IAppleApp extends IApp {
   buildversion: string;
   versionstatus: string;
   sku: boolean;
   category: string;
   accountid: string;
}
```

**IAndroidApp.ts**

```
export interface IAndroidApp extends IApp {
   versioncodes: string;
   track: string;
   rolloutpercentage: boolean;
   acccountname: string;
}
```

Pretty simple models to represent incoming data, nothing fancy.

Now I have a service which makes the API calls and fetches the data as `IApp`.

**apps.service.ts**

```
appVersion: IApp;
appiOSVersion: IAppleApp;
appAndroidVersion: IAndroidApp;

if (this.appVersion.platform === PlatformEnum.ios) {
   this.appiOSVersion = this.appVersion as IAppleApp;
} else if (this.appVersion.platorm === PlatformEnum.android) {
   this.appAndroidVersion = this.appVersion as IAndroidApp;
}
```

And then I use `appsService.appiOSVersion` in `Apple` component, and `appsService.appAndroidVersion` in `Android` component. Both `Apple` and `Android` components have different logic. I tried to use `appsService.appVersion` in each component, but as it's of the base `IApp` type, the object doesn't have platform-specific properties; so have to use two different variables.

My question: Is it possible to reuse `appsService.appVersion` in both `Apple` and `Android` components? (I need this variable to be in `apps.service.ts` for state management). Having two different variables is not crazy, right?

Apologies if this doesn't make sense. Please let me know if you need more details.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At what point are you setting the `this.appVersion.platform` variable? Could you parameterize the fetch call of your `appService` with a generic like `appsService.fetch<T>` and when you call it, parameterize it with your platform specific interface?

That way if you do something like this:
`appService.fetch<IAppleApp>(...)`
You could have the return type be the generic `T` and access that interface's structure.

Comment: Generics! I use a ton of these in my C# API but it didn't cross my mind in TypeScript. Thank you very much for the tip :) (Recently started playing with Angular)